# could not delete PVC in kubernetes foregroundDeletion

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to delete PVC in kubernetes dashboard,I already delete all ElasticSearch service & pods in Kubernetes cluster,the PVC is not protected,this is my pod status:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Document/k8s/work/elasticsearch ⌚ 11:25:38
$ kubectl describe pvc elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0
Name:          elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0
Namespace:     dabai-fat
StorageClass:
Status:        Terminating (lasts 18m)
Volume:        pv001
Labels:        common.k8s.elastic.co/type=elasticsearch
               elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart
               elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name=quickstart-es-default
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [foregroundDeletion]
Capacity:      2Gi
Access Modes:  RWO,ROX,RWX
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                 From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  50m (x42 over 60m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

how to delete this PVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to delete the pvc normally,

```sh
$ kubectl delete pvc <pvc-name> -n <namespace>
```

If it doesn't work, try to delete the `pvc` by removing the finalizers.

```
$ kubectl patch pvc <pvc-name> -n <namespace> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'

$ kubectl delete pvc <pvc-name> -n <namespace>
```